# Unable to get the correct Expected expected response using XPATH Assertions contains regular expression

Tags: regex, web-services, xpath, soap, soapui

I am using below Currency converter Open Source WSDL:

```
http://www.webservicex.com/currencyconvertor.asmx
```

Where I have added below Xpath Assertion to validate the floating ConversationRateResult Response value

```
declare namespace soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
declare namespace ns1='http://www.webserviceX.NET/';
matches(//ns1:ConversationRateResult/text(),'[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]*')
```

But when I am validating it by clicking Select from current Button in XPath Match Configuration window I am getting Expected value as "False" Instead of "True"

Can you please suggest in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try the service and I get the follow result:

```
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <ConversionRateResponse 
            xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
            <ConversionRateResult>0.0079</ConversionRateResult>
        </ConversionRateResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So, note that your `XPath` it's incorrect, the node name is `ConversionRateResult` not `ConversationRateResult`.

Note also that your regex is not working as you expect... in regex `.` operator match any character, to match specifically the `.` you've to escape the char using `\.` So finally I think that the correct regex for your case will be:

`[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*`

Explanation:

`[0-9]+` digits for 1 or more repetitions.

`\.?` is for `.` char but optional (0 or 1)... this is due that maybe the rate could be 1.

`[0-9]*` digit 0 or more repetitions.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks it helps!! . Typo from my side :)

Comment: @HemantVarhekar don't worry it happens `:)`, take a look also at my update, maybe you need to change your regex.

Comment: @ albciff yes it helped. I already modified my assertion like :[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*.